# I want to do a step of for once again

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I want to do a step of for-loop again if a condition is satisfied
like this:

```
for k in range(1,n+1):
    if e[0] < k:
        del end[0]

        go back to same i again
```

is there a way????

Comment: What is i? Did you mean k?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, if you just want to repeat what's under the `if ...` statement over and over until the condition is no longer true, that's exactly what a `while` loop does:

```
for k in range(1,n+1):
    while e[0] < k:
        del end[0]
```

Comment: Obviously since you're not actually changing `e` in the loop, this loop won't end until `end` runs out of items... presumably you meant `e` and `end` to be the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, by the way!

If you want the for-loop again, you could do something like

```
for k in range (1, n+1):
     while e[0] < k:
          del end[0]
```

This is basically saying, while e[0] < k, then execute the del end[0]. If e[0] is not